# Android - Strings.xml versus text files. Which is faster?

Tags: android, text-files, arrays, notepad

I have a dictionary database which contains a total of 99,833 words but separated per letter.
I am testing dictionaryA.txt which contains 3922 words.

Case 1:

When I enter a word I wanna look up, lets say "abacus",
Using a buffered reader, My app says "Thesis is not responding. Wait - Quit". If I choose wait,  it will return the word abacus and its definition.

CODE:

```
InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.definitiona); 
                    try {
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                        String s = in.readLine();
                        String delimiter = " - ";
                        String del[];
                        while(s != null)
                        {
                            s = in.readLine().replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
                            del = s.split(delimiter);
                            if (enhancedStem.equals(del[0]))
                            {
                                in.close();
                                databaseOutput.setText(s);
                                break;
                            }                        
                        }
                        in.close();
                        }
                    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        databaseOutput.setText("" + e);
                    }
                    catch (IOException e1) {
                        databaseOutput.setText("" + e1);
                    }
```

Case 2:

When I enter a word I wanna look up, lets say "abacus",
using the strings.xml (i transferred the whole 3922 words in a string-array), it says the same. I have to click wait before it responds.

CODE:

```
String[] wordA = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.DictionaryA);
                String delimiter = " - ";
                String[] del;
                for (int wordActr = 0; wordActr <= wordA.length - 1; wordActr++)
                {
                    String wordString = wordA[wordActr].toString();
                    del = wordString.split(delimiter);

                    if (enhancedStem.equals(del[0]))
                    {
                        databaseOutput.setText(wordA[wordActr]);
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                        databaseOutput.setText("Word not found!");

                }
```

Can you tell me which is better? Should I keep using my textfile? Or transfer them to the strings.xml since they both respond slowly anyway? And do you have any idea how I can eliminate the "Not responding" problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Doesn't madder, the problem is, that you're freezing the UI by doing heavy lifting on the UI Thread.

Comment: You should be using an actual SQLite database, not a text file or strings.xml.

Comment: You need to implement an asynctask to do the heavy lifting,  because no matter what you do there is a liklihood that you will get an ANR.  Show a progress view while processing the request then update the view with results.

Comment: @VX - Hi! i made an update for the code.

Comment: @Raghav - Well I wanna use an SQLite as well since i read that its the best method but I really dont have the time anymore. Not familiar with SQL codes plus I dont have an sql database for the dictionary.

Comment: @Lukas and Graham - oh i see. So it doesnt have anything to do with my methods? OKay i'll check how I can do this "asynctask" and progress view stuff. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The main advantages of using an Xml over a text file are

1. If has a well defined structure, so parsing it is a easy task.
2. You can also define schema for the xml and there by you can traverse through the xml pretty easily and it becomes type safe.
3. Better performance.
4. More reliable.

so its better to use xml ...

Comment: Thank you! I'll go for xml method then! :)

Answer (score 1):

You are encountering the wait message because you perform a heavy operation in the main thread. You can eliminate the wait message by using [Threads](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) or [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Usage of strings.xml is recommended by Google for use cases similar to yours

Comment: Thank you for the response! i'll check on the links!

Answer (score 1):

If you'd show some code, this would be easier. My first guess is that since your UI is not responding, you're doing the "search task" on the UI thread. Executing heavy tasks on the UI thread is generally not a good idea, instead you should look into AsyncTasks, Threads or something else, whatever suits best.
By executing the task in the background, the user can still interact with your application - for example stop the search task if he has a typo in his search or simply does not care anymore. Until the search is done and the results are fetched, you can simply display some sort of wait-dialog.

Which one of your two suggestions is faster I can't tell. You could create two threads, both doing one way and measure the time.

Comment: Hello! I updated the code. Thank you for the information. I think thats what I'm doing since I did not put any code about Threads and AsyncTasks. I'll check on the site how can this be done. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

99,833 words can be stored in less than 2 MB

In that case the fastest is to keep in memory, so the case 3 :)

Comment: Can you tell me how I can shrink it to 2 mb?

Comment: read all into ArrayList<String> or other collection, maybe you need a key-value pair: Hashtable or something like that, unsynchronized version is faster than synchoronized ones. To store in persistence I would use binary file, and for sure not xml