# Android - Passing String to Asynctask?

Tags: android, string, android-asynctask, parameter-passing

*Related to my previous question about ANR problem ([Android - Strings.xml versus text files. Which is faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15135371/android-strings-xml-versus-text-files-which-is-faster)).*

I tried using AsyncTask as advised by the respondents but i'm at a loss now.

I need to pass a string from my menu activity to an Asynctask but it's really confusing me. I've been searching and studying for 5 hours already but still cannot do it.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    /** Create an option menu from res/menu/items.xml */
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.items, menu);

    /** Get the action view of the menu item whose id is search */
    View v = (View) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();

    /** Get the edit text from the action view */
    final EditText txtSearch = ( EditText ) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_search);

    /** Setting an action listener */
    txtSearch.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

            final EditText txtSearch = ( EditText ) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_search);
            String enhancedStem = txtSearch.getText().toString();
            TextView databaseOutput = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView8);

            new AsyncTaskRunner().execute();
            // should I put "enhancedStem" inside execute?
            }
          });
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Here's the Async part: **UPDATED**

```
public class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
      String curEnhancedStem;
      private ProgressDialog pdia;

      public AsyncTaskRunner (String enhancedStem)
      {
           this.curEnhancedStem = enhancedStem;
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
       // Things to be done before execution of long running operation. For
       // example showing ProgessDialog
          super.onPreExecute();
          pdia = ProgressDialog.show(secondactivity.this, "" , "Searching for words");
      }



    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        if(curEnhancedStem.startsWith("a"))
        {
            String[] wordA = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.DictionaryA);
            String delimiter = " - ";
            String[] del;
            TextView databaseOutput1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView8);
            for (int wordActr = 0; wordActr <= wordA.length - 1; wordActr++)
            {
                String wordString = wordA[wordActr].toString();
                del = wordString.split(delimiter);

                if (curEnhancedStem.equals(del[0]))
                {
                    databaseOutput1.setText(wordA[wordActr]);
                    pdia.dismiss();
                    break;
                }
                else
                    databaseOutput1.setText("Word not found!");
            }
        }

       return null;
      } 


      @Override
      protected void onProgressUpdate(String... text) {
       // Things to be done while execution of long running operation is in
       // progress. For example updating ProgessDialog

      }

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
       // execution of result of Long time consuming operation
      }
}
```

Retrieval now works. I saw it display the word being looked for but it terminated suddenly.
Maybe because, like what you mentioned, UI stuff should be done on the post execute.
If that's the case, what should I return on the doInBackground() part then pass on the onPostExecute()?

(Thanks a lot guys! I'm close to making this work properly now!)

Comment: I don't mean to be a killjoy, at all, but this code really is not close to working properly.  The reference to the textView, from inside the doInBackground method is going to fail.  You cannot touch the UI except from the UI thread.  I'm sure it isn't what you want to hear but, now that you know a little more about how this stuff works, you might want to pause, read up on Android architecture, and start again.

Comment: yup! i already read and studied several stuffs about Asynctask and that issue is already fixed. Thank you for the reminder! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the problem, they are local to the method that you declared them in then you are declaring an `AsyncTask` class which doesn't have access to them. If the `AsyncTask` is an inner class of your menu activity then you can declare them as member variables.

```
public class MenuActivity extends Activity
{
     String enhancedStem;
     ....
```

If it is a separate class then you can create a constructor in your `Async` class and pass the variable to the constructor.

```
public class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
  String curEnhancedStem;
  private ProgressDialog pdia;

  public void AsyncTaskRunner (String variableName)
{
     this.curEnhancedStem = variableName;
}
```

And call it like

```
 AsyncTaskRunner newTask = new AsyncTaskRunner(enhancedStem);
 newTask.execute();
```

Also, you can't do `UI` stuff in `doInBackground` so this will need to be changed in the `Activity` class or one of your other methods in the `Async` class such as `onPostExecute()` if it is an inner class. Otherwise, you can pass a value back to your menu activity to update your `TextView`

**Edit**

You are still trying to change the `UI` in `doInBackground()` with this

```
TextView databaseOutput1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView8);
```

then again when you call `setText()`. This needs to be put in your `onPostExecute()` but then you will need to pass a reference of your `TextView` to the `AsyncTask`. You could just pass back the `String` that you want to set the text as from your `onPostExecute()` and set it in your `Activity`. Hope this helps

Comment: I agree about the second part(not accessing UI elements until you get to onPostExecute), but I think the first part is kind of misleading. You can access the private variables of the class via the syntax I showed in my answer.

Comment: Not if it is declared as a local variable to a method. If it were a member variable of the class you could

Comment: well, yeah. But if it's a local variable to the method, you could of course make the variables of the calling class publicly visible (which would be horrible design, but I digress).

Comment: @DigCamara you can't make them public if they are declared inside a method. They would still have to have class scope

Comment: Hi! I made an update and it works now! Thanks a lot. But after it shows onscreen the definition of the word, it force closes.

Comment: I have edited my answer. You CAN'T do `UI` stuff in `doInBackground()`

Comment: Hi! Managed to make it work properly now! thanks a lot! though I had to switch back to using textfiles since apparently, XMLs cant handle my word database

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a constructor for your `AsyncTaskRunner` class.
2. Pass both a `Context` (your Activity Context) and the `databaseOutput` `TextView` as  arguments to your `AsyncTaskRunner` class constructor.
3. Save references to those two objects in `AsyncTaskRunner`.
4. Pass `enhancedStem` to the `execute()` method.
5. Use the `Context` you passed to the constructor as the first argument to `ProgessDialog.show()`
6. You cannot access `databaseOutput` from the `doInBackground()` method. You must only access it in `onPostExecute()`, which runs on the UI thread. So, use the reference to `databseOutput` which you passed to the constructor to update the TextView in the `onPostExecute()` method accordingly.

As a note, anything you return from the `doInBackground()` method will be available to you as the parameters of the `onPostExecute()` method.

Please refer to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

I would recommend you pass the required data rather than accessing it using the enclosing class - this makes your `ASyncTaskRunner` much more flexible, and is generally better practice.